# Google Recaptcha not working in TOR Browser

Tags: error, google, verification, captcha, login

In our website we provide Google Recaptcha V2 for users during login process, and the user must clear the Recaptcha verification before they can login else the user cannot login to the website. This process works for most of the users.

But the TOR browser users cannot solve the Recaptcha as they get a message "Your computer or network may be sending automated queries. To protect our users we can't process your request right now". This prevents our TOR browser users from accessing our site.

Is there any way by which we can specifically allow the TOR users to bypass the Recaptcha verification so that they can login without any trouble? Or are there any alternatives Recaptchas (apart from Google Recaptcha) that are TOR friendly?

Comment: since this question is not entirely about Tor itself, maybe - especially for the alternatives part - the guys at [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) can also help (although crossposting is not so welcome). - perhaps linking this question and elaborate the requirements for an alternative a bit more would be fine.

Comment: Change the identity for the site and not a tedious of changing the tor circuit. I mean, go to the main Google page, change the site identity, and try the search again. Repeat this until it allows you to reach the search page. In latest version this can be done by Ctrl+Shift+L (only site identity not the tor circuit since it is tedious. If you wish to change the tor circuit then choose to press Ctrl+U).

Comment: this question is about recaptcha and not about google-search...

Answer (score 1):

> the TOR browser users cannot solve the Recaptcha as they get a message "Your computer or network may be sending automated queries. To protect our users we can't process your request right now". This prevents our TOR browser users from accessing our site.

Actually there is nothing wrong with the Tor Browser. The problem is Google. Google sees that the user us coming from a Tor exit node and is therefore putting the user into a never ending loop.

Your options are:

1. Contact Google support to allow users who come from Tor exit nodes
2. Stop using Captcha
3. Not allow users who use Tor to access your site.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try [hCaptcha](https://www.hcaptcha.com/).
It's an alternative to Google's ReCaptcha.

From their website: "It is the most popular reCAPTCHA alternative"